# Pass Ajax variable value as response data name

Tags: ajax, laravel

Please I am trying to pass textbox value as Ajax response data name. But its not working. Is there anyway to achieve it ?

I want to pass `var grp_id = $('#group_id').val();` variable into ajax response name `$("#freight").val(data.grp_id);` the sample values of `grp_id` will be Short

I want like `var grp_id = Short;` and in response `$("#freight").val(data.Short);`

```
 $(document).on('change','#product_id',function () {
        var prod_id=$(this).val();
        var a=$(this).parent();            
        var grp_id = $('#group_id').val();

       // console.log(dest_id);
        $.ajax({
            type:'get',
            url:'{!!URL::to('findPrice')!!}',
            data:{'prod_id':prod_id,'grp_id':grp_id},
            dataType:'json',//return data will be json
            success:function(data){
               // console.log("title");
               // console.log(data.title);
                $("#freight").val(data.grp_id);
            },
            error:function(){

            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).on('change','#product_id',function () {
    var prod_id=$(this).val();
    var a=$(this).parent();            
    var grp_id = $('#group_id').val();

    $.ajax({
        type:'get',
        url:'{!!URL::to('findPrice')!!}',
        data:{'prod_id':prod_id,'grp_id':grp_id},
        dataType:'json',//return data will be json
        success:function(data){
            $("#freight").val(data[grp_id]);
        },
        error:function(){

        }
    });
});
```

`$("#freight").val(data[grp_id]);` should do the trick this will return the value of `data.short` if `grp_id = "short"`. What you are doing is on the data object looking for a grp_id key that most likely does not exist and is returning undefined.